# Do I have to recreate tables as models for an existing database?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I'm just starting with Python and Django and have an existing database. I'd like to create views to edit the fields in this database, do I have to create models to match these tables or is there a way to start editing after connecting the database and a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage the schema manually, for example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'CENSUS_PERSONS'
```

This can be an option, but I would recommend to let Django ORM manage them, by creating the models from scratch and doing a database migration.

More details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases/